# Instead of adding value i'm replacing the value of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi all i'm trying to get an array of Sizes and Color which is inside an object. So when we click on the input a handler will be call i.e., clickHandler() but the code when run it replacing the value of the array each time when the handler is invoked.

```
export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [attributes, setAttributes] = React.useState([]);
  const [filterArray, setFilterArray] = React.useState({
     Size: [],
     Color: []
  });
  
  const clickHandler = (n, v)  => {
    setFilterArray({...filterArray, [n]:v})
  }


  React.useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3004/attributes')
      .then(res => setAttributes(res.data))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  },[])

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Dynamic Filter
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <div className='text-left'>
          <Typography variant='h6' className='m-2'>
              Filters
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <div className="list-conntainer" style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}>
            <List>
                {
                    attributes.length > 0 && attributes.map((attribute, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className='mb-5' key={index}>
                                <h4>{attribute.att_id}</h4>
                                {
                                    attribute.att_value.map((v, index) => {
                                       return (
    
                                            <div className="form-check mb-1">
                                                <input className="form-check-input" onClick={() => clickHandler(attribute.att_id, v)} type="checkbox"  />
                                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">{v}</label>
                                            </div>
                                    
                                       )}
                                    )
                                }
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </List>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <CardContainer filterArray={filterArray} />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Inside the handler i'm passing two arguments which are key and value. The key can be either Size or Color.

let me also share the json folder.

```
"attributes": [
        {
            "att_id": "Size",
            "att_value":[ "S", "M", "2XL", "L", "XL", "XS", "3XL" ]
        },
        {
            "att_id": "Color",
            "att_value": ["Red", "Blue", "Silver", "Green", "Yellow", "Black"]
        }
```

My desire output is: { Size: [S, M, L], Color: [Red, Blue] }.

But Actual Output which i getting is : { Size: M, Color: Red }.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is both syntaxic and logical.
syntaxic because in your click handler you are replacing the array by a single value indeed. This can be changed like this:

```
const clickHandler = (name, value) => {
let newArr = filterArray[name];
if (!newArr.includes(value)){
    newArr.push(value)
} else {
   //remove value from array
}
setFilterArray(...filterArray, [name]: newArr);
}
```

I think in your case having arrays of booleans for the filterArray would make more sense and be more efficient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sophia Koulen this is the answer which i'm looking for ...